# Can Synapse Spark connect to a "Log Analytics workspace"?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, adx

I need to export from "Log Analytics workspace" to storage account in parquet / delta format.  How can I achieve this?

Using the ADX Spark connector in a Notebook, it says that the URL is invalid. I’m using the URL of LAW instead of a cluster of AdX.

Answer (score 0):

With a diffrent appraoch apart from ADX/Notebook, we can run the logic application afterwards and look for logs in the storage.

To learn more about Using a Logic App to archive data from the Log Analytics workspace to Azure storage, consult the Microsoft Documentation..

[image]

To do this, we only need access to the Log Analytics Workspace and Storage accounts.

Additionally, we can construct a trigger in the logic app that will run once daily or as frequently as needed to upload all the new data..

[image]

After the device has been activated, click Add New step to add an action that runs after the recurring action. Click "Azure Monitor Logs" after typing "azure monitor" into the "Choose an action" box. After setting up the full workflow, make a blob and attach it to the workflow as shown below:

[image]

Later, we can execute the logic application and search the log store.

Reference link: Microsoft Documentation
[Export data from a Log Analytics workspace to a storage account by using Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app)